# adding views to bin deploy set causes error

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, web-deployment

I am setting up an ASP.Net MVC app for bin deployment. Since I would like to include the compiled views in the release I followed the advice from Steven Sanderson's Pro MVC book and changed my app.csproj file to include

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

Unfortunately, this change is causing me a build error.

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\Users\sylvie\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\app\app\obj\release\package\packagetmp\web.config
```

Any idea how to either deal with the error message or get the compiled views into the bin dir in a different way?

Thanks!
Duffy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile your views. That's the job of ASP.NET. You could simply go through [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) and everything should work just fine.

Comment: I have read the blog post and it was helpfull. However, Steven Sanderson's tip is about compiling views to catch compile time errors in the views at publish time. You don't have to do this but if you don't you'll end up with the occasional broken view in production.

Comment: @duffy, aren't you running your site on your dev machine before deploying on production to make sure there are not errors? Don't you have some web tests using Selenium or some other web test framework set up to verify the behavior of your web site as part of your continuous integration process before deploying to production? If the answer to those questions is no, then maybe you should consider doing it.

Comment: I think eliminating compile time errors comes before setting up web tests. The page is still under development so writing web tests for every page is not top of my list at this point. However, a simple compile of the views is, since it will immediately catch the most obvious renaming errors.

Comment: This slows down pages considerably for the first or 2nd load (which can be significant if your user base is small, you release frequently, and you have hundreds of views).  Seems like there should be an easy way to send the compiled views via msdeploy.